# Coldfusion Json from structure

Tags: json, coldfusion

I'm using this code

```
<cfset user_data = StructNew() />
<cfset user_data[["field_a"]["und"]["tid"] = '123' />
```

`<cfset json = SerializeJSON(user_data)>`

It generates this json

```
{"und":{"tid":123}}
```

I would like to have the json look like this instead

```
{"und":[{"tid":123}]}
```

How do I have to change the struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following cfscript:

```
user_data = { 'und' = [ { 'tid' = '123' } ] };
json = serializeJSON(user_data);
```

you're not putting the key/value pair in an array as needed by your request.

Comment: excellent, that worked, thanks. Is it possible without cfscript as well?

Comment: Yes, just use tags.

    <cfset user_data = { 'und' = [ { 'tid' = '123' } ] }>